# I want to make fields required

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

I want to make all fields required on this register screen. If user leave any field empty, I want to give him warning like "Enter your name" or whatever the field is, based on the field name, I want to give error. Please let me know What changed I have to change in this code.

```
class MyRegister extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyRegister({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  static GetStorage emailStorage=GetStorage();
  static GetStorage passwordStorage=GetStorage();

  @override
  _MyRegisterState createState() => _MyRegisterState();
}

class _MyRegisterState extends State<MyRegister> {
  TextEditingController fullnamecontroller = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController emailcontroller = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController passwordcontroller = TextEditingController();
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // String email = '', password = '';
    return Container(
      decoration: const BoxDecoration(
        image: DecorationImage(
            image: AssetImage('assets/register.png'), fit: BoxFit.cover),
      ),
      child: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
        appBar: AppBar(
          backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
          elevation: 0,
        ),
        body: Stack(
          children: [
            Container(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 35, top: 30),
              child: const Text(
                'Create Account',
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 33),
              ),
            ),
            SingleChildScrollView(
              child: Container(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                    top: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.28),
                child: Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: [
                    Container(
                      margin: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 35, right: 35),
                      child: Column(
                        children: [
                          Form(
                            child: TextFormField(
                              controller: fullnamecontroller,
                              style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                              decoration: InputDecoration(
                                enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                                  borderSide: const BorderSide(
                                    color: Colors.white,
                                  ),
                                ),
                                focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                                  borderSide: const BorderSide(
                                    color: Colors.black,
                                  ),
                                ),
                                hintText: "Full Name",
                                hintStyle: const TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                                border: OutlineInputBorder(
                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                                ),
                              ),
                          
                          
                              
                              validator: (value) {
                                if (value!.isNotEmpty && value.length > 3) {
                                  return null;
                                } else if (value.length < 4 && value.isNotEmpty){
                                  return 'Please enter your valid name';
                                } else {
                                  return 'Enter your name here';
                                }
                              },
                            ),
                          ),
                          
                          const SizedBox(
                            height: 30,
                          ),
                          
                          Form(
                            child: TextFormField(
                              style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                              decoration: InputDecoration(
                                  enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                                    borderSide: const BorderSide(
                                      color: Colors.white,
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                  
                                  focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                                    borderSide: const BorderSide(
                                      color: Colors.black,
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                  hintText: "Profession",
                                  hintStyle: const TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                                  border: OutlineInputBorder(
                                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                                  )),
                            ),
                          ),
                          const SizedBox(
                            height: 30,
                          ),
                          TextFormField(
                            style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                            decoration: InputDecoration(
                                enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                                  borderSide: const BorderSide(
                                    color: Colors.white,
                                  ),
                                ),
                                focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                                  borderSide: const BorderSide(
                                    color: Colors.black,
                                  ),
                                ),
                                hintText: "Where Are You From",
                                hintStyle: const TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                                border: OutlineInputBorder(
                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                                )),
                          ),
                          const SizedBox(
                            height: 30,
                          ),
                          TextFormField(
                            // controller: TextEditingcontroller(emailcontroller),
                            onChanged: (value) {
                              emailcontroller.text = value;
                            },
                            
                            style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                            decoration: InputDecoration(
                              enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                                borderSide: const BorderSide(
                                  color: Colors.white,
                                ),
                              ),
                              focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                                borderSide: const BorderSide(
                                  color: Colors.black,
                                ),
                              ),
                              // final myController = TextEditingController();
                              hintText: "Email",
                              hintStyle: const TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                              border: OutlineInputBorder(
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                          const SizedBox(
                            height: 30,
                          ),
                          TextFormField(
                            // controller: passwordcontroller,
                            onChanged: (value) {
                              passwordcontroller.text = value;
                            },
                            style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                            obscureText: true,
                            decoration: InputDecoration(
                              enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                                borderSide: const BorderSide(
                                  color: Colors.white,
                                ),
                              ),
                              focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                                borderSide: const BorderSide(
                                  color: Colors.black,
                                ),
                              ),
                              hintText: "Password",
                              hintStyle: const TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                              border: OutlineInputBorder(
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                          const SizedBox(
                            height: 40,
                          ),
                          Row(
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                            children: [
                              const Text(
                                'Sign Up',
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    color: Colors.white,
                                    fontSize: 27,
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w700),
                              ),
                              CircleAvatar(
                                radius: 30,
                                backgroundColor: const Color(0xff4c505b),
                                child: IconButton(
                                    color: Colors.white,
                                    onPressed: () async {
                                      try {
                                        UserCredential userCredential =
                                            await FirebaseAuth.instance
                                                .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
                                          email: emailcontroller.text,
                                          password: passwordcontroller.text,
                                        );
                                        MyRegister.emailStorage.write('email', emailcontroller.text);
                                        MyRegister.passwordStorage.write('password', passwordcontroller.text);
                                      } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
                                        if (e.code == 'weak-password') {
                                          debugPrint('Your password is too weak');
                                        } else if (e.code ==
                                            'email-already-in-use') {
                                          debugPrint(
                                              'The account already exist with this Email.');
                                        }
                                      } catch (e) {
                                        print(e);
                                      }
                                      Navigator.push(
                                        context,
                                        MaterialPageRoute(
                                            builder: (context) =>
                                                const Start()),
                                      );
                                    },
                                    icon: const Icon(
                                      Icons.arrow_forward,
                                    )),
                              )
                            ],
                          ),
                          const SizedBox(
                            height: 40,
                          ),
                          Row(
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                            children: [
                              TextButton(
                                onPressed: () {
                                  Navigator.pushNamed(context, 'login');
                                },
                                child: const Text(
                                  'Sign In',
                                  textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                      decoration: TextDecoration.underline,
                                      color: Colors.white,
                                      fontSize: 18),
                                ),
                                style: const ButtonStyle(),
                              ),
                            ],
                          )
                        ],
                      ),
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

This is the full code of my file, please let me know what changes have to do in it to make every field required and show warning when it will empty.

Answer (score 0):

To add a validation to a textfield use validators

```
TextFormField(
  // The validator receives the text that the user has entered.
  validator: (value) {
    if (value == null || value.isEmpty) {
      return 'Please enter some text';
    }
    return null;
  },
),
```

Then to validate all fields. Wrap the Column which holds all text field and button in a Form widget.. create a global key for the form

```
final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
```

Assign this key to the form

```
Form(
  key: _formKey,
  child: Column(),//all textfields and button in this column
)
```

And on button click add this code

```
ElevatedButton(
  onPressed: () {

    if (_formKey.currentState!.validate()) {
      // If the form is valid, display a snackbar. In the real world,
      // you'd often call a server or save the information in a database.
      ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
        const SnackBar(content: Text('Processing Data')),
      );
    }
  },
  child: const Text('Submit'),
),
```